# Installing Apache HTTP Server v2.2.14 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, freeze, apache-http-server

I am trying to install Apache HTTP Server v2.2.14 on a machine recently upgraded to Windows 7.  It worked fine under Windows XP, but when I go to install this in Windows 7, the install script appears to hang.  In the install wizard dialog it states:

```
Installing Apache HTTP Server 2.2.14
The program features you selected are being installed.

Please wait while the Installation Wizard installs Apache HTTP Server 2.2.14. This may take several minutes.

Status:

<progress bar with thin sliver at left edge that makes no progress>
```

I tried with and without openSSL support, both fail the same way.

Is this known to work on Windows 7?  If so, how do I debug what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Windows 7 is not impressing me.  I figured out the issue.  There was a dialog hidden underneath the install wizard asking if I really wanted to run the install because it was from an unknown source.  I would expect any such dialog to be raised above not below.  Only by accident did I discover it was lying in wait hidden below.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to install Apache on a version of Windows 7 with BranchCache enabled?

If [BranchCache](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637832%28WS.10%29.aspx) is enabled, [port 80](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd837646%28WS.10%29.aspx) is used by Windows.

Comment: Seems strange that the install would need port 80 access.  Is BranchCache enabled by default on Windows 7?  I have made no changes that I am aware of to how it is set by the install of Windows 7 by default.

Comment: Branchcache is only available on Enterprise/Ultimate for Windows 7.  You can use `netstat -a` or a program like TcpView from SysInternals to determine if anything is locally listening on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

This link has a nice detailed tutorial

http://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-and-mysql-5-5-21-on-windows-7/

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)